# Disabled text selection

Tags: css, text, selection

I created my own checkbox because now I can just use images as checkboxes (no styling needed). To make this work I toggle a `<div>` between two classes (`checked` & `unchecked`). This works perfectly, but my one problem is when you check back and forth a few times then the text around the `<div>` starts highlighting it self.

**How can I stop the text around the `<div>` from being highlighted?**

Here is an example of what happens when you check/uncheck a few times:
[image]

Here is a stackblitz to play with:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgxkgk

Comment: _“[…] (no styling needed)”_ - and accessibility _terrible_ … seriously, this is how it should _not_ be done.

Comment: @misorude It is not my fault some html elements are basically impossible to style (have you tried styling an <option> ?)

Comment: Options and Checkboxes/Radio buttons are two different things. The solutions for “custom” checkboxes/radio buttons that still use the actual form elements plus labels (and therefor have way better usability, than trying to “fake” this using divs), have existed for years now …